# How to use the parent selector as a suffix with Sass

Tags: sass

I know that

```
.bg {
    &-orange { background-color: $orange; }
    &-yellow { background-color: $yellow; }
    &-blue { background-color: $blue; }
    &-green { background-color: $green; }
}
```

Will turn into

```
.bg-orange { background-color: $orange; }
.bg-yellow { background-color: $yellow; }
.bg-blue { background-color: $blue; }
.bg-green { background-color: $green; }
```

But what if I want the "**bg**" at the end?

```
.orange-bg { background-color: $orange; }
.yellow-bg { background-color: $yellow; }
.blue-bg { background-color: $blue; }
.green-bg { background-color: $green; }
```

How can I accomplish this with SASS? Any ideas?

Comment: No shortcut there. You don't have inverse tree structures.

Comment: It would be great having them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution

```
-bg {

    @at-root #{selector-append(".orange", &)} {
        color:orange;
    }// Here's the solution:
    @at-root #{selector-append(".yellow", &)} {
        color:yellow;
    }// Here's the solution:
    @at-root #{selector-append(".blue", &)} {
        color:blue;
    }
    @at-root #{selector-append(".green", &)} {
        color:green;
    }
}
```

Will compile to

```
.orange-bg {
  color: orange;
}
.yellow-bg {
  color: yellow;
}
.blue-bg {
  color: blue;
}
.green-bg {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is the most accurate, no mixins and less verbose way to resolve this. I hope Sass do something about it to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is where mixin's become your friend : [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/ZMJxdx)

```
@mixin sassyExample($color, $attrib) {
  #{'.' + $color + '-' + $attrib} {
   background-color: unquote($color); 
  }
}

@include sassyExample('orange', 'bg');
@include sassyExample('red', 'bg');
@include sassyExample('yellow', 'bg');
```

You could go cooler and map and loop your colors to assign whatever, or add a param to swap the color/attrib places, etc, but this is just a quick proof of concept. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chris! I'll try some work around.

Comment: @Bengala No problem, let me know if you had something more specific in mind and we'll get you sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent selector using ampersand in functions and mixins without having to pass it as a parameter.

I would probably do something like that [(demo)](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/46c141eec8fec8811348a7b26cb040bd):

```
@mixin pre($modifier) {
  $ampersand: & + '';

  $parents-list: simple-selectors(str-replace($ampersand, ' ', ''));

  $suffix: nth($parents-list, -1) + '';
  $suffix-type: str-slice($suffix, 1, 1);
  $suffix-name: str-slice($suffix, 2, -1);

  $ascendant-selectors: str-replace($ampersand, $suffix, '');
  $current-selector: '#{$suffix-type}#{$modifier}-#{$suffix-name}';

  @at-root {
     #{$ascendant-selectors}#{$current-selector} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

To make it work, you will need a **string replacement function** as well ([from Hugo Giraudel](https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/13/sass-string-replacement-function/)):

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }
  @return $string;
}
```

### How it works:

**SCSS**

```
.bg {
  color: red;

  @include pre(blue) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
.bg {
  color: red;
}

.blue-bg {
  color: blue;
}
```

### Use cases:

- .foo
- span.foo
- span .foo
- .foo .bar
- .foo.bar

> You can use **ID**s as well.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion Quentin, the thing is I believe there should be a better way than using mixins, of course that helps a lot but it should be easier. Sorry for the late.